# How to resolve rebalance issue or duplication of record in spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am always worried about Kafka about
   1. Duplications
   2. Missing record

I have done below changes to solve above issue in spring Kafka 2.2.2.RELEASE.
Could someone please confirm if this is the correct.

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 20);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
return factory;
```

Also please confirm, do I need to implement ConsumerRebalanceListener in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.

if require how to implement.

```
   factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
            //TODO code 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
            //TODO code
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you can provide some example saying we got this record duplicate or missing something in total records will be helpful

Comment: After adding below configuration I am not gating duplicate record. props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 20);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);             Before that I got duplicate record in our log. So is this ok? But currently I am getting some records are missing. So I am analyzing that

Comment: suppose millions of record coming to the kafka consumer, Is this above configuration ok.        
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 20); props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);                or do I need to change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka provide 3 delivery guarantees: at most once, at least once, exactly once.

If you data is located only in Kafka and your processing result are write in Kafka, you can get exactly once delivery guarantee(see here Kafka Streams library).

If you work with external systems, example other databases, Kafka can guarantee at most once, at least once. In this scenario, your app must ensure that messages received from Kafka are not processed twice. Your app can do that by saving all processed messages in database and when a new message will be received, the app will check first if that message was processed or not.

For more information about this read:

[Message Reliability In Kafka](https://lunatech.com/blog/XWT5axAAACYAMtPv/message-reliability-in-kafka)

[Kafka Consumer](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html)

EDIT:

MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG is very high. If your message will be processed and save in database, 30 seconds is enough.